# Memory leak sql server 2000

Tags: memory-leaks, sql-server-2000, windows-server-2003, sql-server-profiler

there!
I use MS Sql server 8.0.
I have big problem with memory leak in it.
The physical memory, that is used by ms sql server can up to 900 MB. My question is can it be by bug in ms sql server or it is impossible?

Comment: You need to show code, give more info, etc.

Comment: How many databases? What size are they each? How active have you been querying? How long in hours has the service been running?

Comment: I made experiment:
I run my mvc app in firefox. After that memory usage is upped. After I close window memory will not return to previous level. But not connection exists to this db because i try to take it off-line and its fine. What it can be?

Comment: By the way one more thing, when I run in sql analyzer query:
`execute sp_who`
It shows me a lot of records, that have status sleeping.
In what way I can change time of living sleeping connection in connections pool?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that SQL Server is using 900 MB is no indication of a bug.  Databases aggressively cache to improve performance.  I'm actually surprised that 900MB is the highest you've seen.

Comment: On my server total size of dbs is about 6900 MB.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto recursive's answer, if you are on a development box where you want to limit it, you can run a query something like this:

```
use master
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'max server memory', 512
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

This will limit it to 512 MB. I would **not** limit your SQL server's memory usage in a production environment without carefully understanding the effects of it. The minimum, I believe, is 4 MB. Depending on what queries you run, how much data there is, and how it is organized, below 256 might starve SQL of memory.